# Javascript/Laravel only First ID works for button

Tags: javascript, php, loops, laravel-5

I am using laravel and am looping to display all my users with an edit button. I want to hide the user edit form with javascript and have it appear on click. This works for the first item in my array, but when I try to edit a second user, the button won't work. Is there a way to insert an id into the form directly with laravel? I know it's because id is being reiterated, but all I'm not sure how to fix that.

users.index

```
@extends('layouts.admin')


@section('content')



<div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="panel">


        @if($users)
        @foreach($users as $user)

        <p>{!! $user->name !!}</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="edit-user"> Edit</button>
        <hr>
        <div class="edit-user">
        <h1>Edit Users</h1>

            {!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=>'AccountController@store']) !!}

                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('name', 'Client Name:') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                </div>
                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('start_access_date', 'start:') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('start_access_date', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                </div>
                    {{ csrf_field() }}


                    <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('end_access_date', 'end:') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('end_access_date', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                </div>
                    {{ csrf_field() }}


                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::submit('Edit Account', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
                </div>

            {!! Form::close() !!}


        </div>
 @endforeach
        @endif



            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.date').datepicker({  

       format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'

     });  

</script>  
  <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

//if you wish to keep both the divs hidden by default then dont forget to hide //them           
$(".edit-user").hide();



$("#edit-user").click(function(){
      $(".edit-user").toggle();

});

});



</script>
    @endsection
```

Comment: Duplicate id problem

Comment: Remove *id=edit-user* from your button code. In handler use *$("button.edit-user").click*.

Comment: <button class="btn btn-primary " > Edit</button> /// $("button.edit-user").click(function(){
      $(".edit-user").toggle(); like this? The button came back without a function

Comment: In code you provided your button had a class *edit-user*, so I used it. In the comment the button has only bootstrap btn classes but no class *edit-user*. Where is it gone? Well, you don't need exactly this class. The idea is just to replace id's with classes, so that many of them (not just one) could be processed by js.

Comment: I just saw your response, sorry yeah my buttons kept not appearing with that class. I will edit my original question. I had to change it to $("button").click, without the edit-user class. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Be carefull with $("button").click. It will fire on any button clicked, not just that one to edit user.

Comment: Then how do I add a class to a button since I cannot reiterate the ID?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" class="edit-user-btn" data-id="{!! $user->id !!}"> Edit</button>
```

instead of

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="edit-user"> Edit</button>
```

And Then `javascript` like this:

```
$(".edit-user-btn").click(function(){
  // here You might use id for your form label
  // var user_id = $(this).data("id");
  $(".edit-user").toggle();
```

});